# The position of a car at time $t$ is given by the function $p (t)=t^2−t−7$. What is the velocity when $p(t)=5$?

Tags: calculus

> The position of a car at time $t$ is given by the function $p (t)=t^2−t−7$. What is the velocity when $p(t)=5$? Assume $t\ge0$.

Setting $t^2-t-7=5$ yields $t=-3$ or $t=4$

Setting the derivative of $p(t)$ equal to $5$, which is $2t-1$, yields $t=3$. So the instantaneous velocity at $p(t)=5$ is $3$…

The test's correct answer is $7$. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $p(t)=5$, you have $t=4$. And $p'(4)=2\times4-1=7$.

Solving $p'(t)=5$ tells you at which moment the speed is equal to $5$, but that is not what is being asked.

Comment: Ah.. I forgot to plug it back in. Thank you!